# rspec superclass mismatch TestRequest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, cucumber

My rspec & cucumber were running fine. Suddenly I'm getting this error when trying to run rspec or cucumber:

```
superclass mismatch for class TestRequest (TypeError)
```

here is the stack trace

```
opt/boxen/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.17/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:151:in `<module:ActionController>': superclass mismatch for class TestRequest (TypeError)
    from /opt/boxen/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.17/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/boxen/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-rails-2.14.1/lib/rspec/rails/example/controller_example_group.rb:9:in `<module:ControllerExampleGroup>'
    from /opt/boxen/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-rails-2.14.1/lib/rspec/rails/example/controller_example_group.rb:6:in `<module:Rails>'
...
```

I did kill a test mid stream in Spring and I know that can sometimes cause problems. 
I am on Rails 3.2.17 ruby 1.9.3p448 Rspec 2.14.7

That seems to imply that I have 2 TestRequest objects somewhere in my rails environment?
Thanks for help.

Comment: I have searched through my source and have no TestRequest classes. Next I suppose I should search though all my gems. Thanks for any insight, rather stumped.

Comment: Did you stop all spring services with `bin/spring stop`? I suspect the TestRequest is part of rspec-rails. Did you update any gems lately?

Comment: I did spring stop - didnt help. I also took spring out of gemfile and bundle installed it out - didnt help - so I dont think spring is the problem. None of my colleagues are having this issue working off same code/github. No recent gemfile changes, most recent is 2 months ago rack-cors was added.

Comment: If I go into the test_case.rb file where the error triggers from and I comment out the subclassing of ActionDispatch::TestRequest of TestRequest then it is happy, but this of course does not feel like a proper solution.